# Can I have more than 2 power plans in Windows 10 21H2?

Tags: windows-10, power-management, windows-10-v21h2

**Is it possible to have more than 2 power plans in Windows 10 21H2?**

On my Lenovo P51 I had two default plans: battery optimized and balanced if I remember correctly.

I have added third "High performance" power plan (user defined) to have high performance on battery. One of old, default plans disappeared (from both "old" and "new" control panel). I don't have "Hidden" power plans like here ([screenshot source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-change-power-plan-settings-windows-10-a.html)):

[image]

Can I have 3 selectable from tray icon power plans by doing some registry tweak or is it hardcoded somewhere? At this moment I have registry tweaked tray icon so it shows power plans like Windows 7 (done by Ultimate Windows Tweaker 4.8).

I think I had that issue also in Windows 7, but I had power management software from Lenovo and I could select power plans from longer list, now that software is not available for Windows 10 and it is bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional power plans, but they are not predefined.

Start, Settings, System, Power and Sleep.

Then click on Additional Power Settings.

In the Window that comes up, use Create a Power Plan.

There are 3 pre-defined Plans and you can create your own and give it a plan name.  That gives you at least 4 plans.

I provided a screen shot to assist you.

This is all that is natively available in Windows 10.  It may depend on computer manufacturer but I took my screen shot from a Lenovo laptop.

Windows 11 has more if you are able to upgrade and wish to upgrade.

[image: Windows 10 21H2 Power Plans]

Comment: I already did it. And it removed one of old plans. But now when I added one more plan - I have 3 (in Control Panel), but I see just 2 of them in system tray (one is hidden, as Control Panel says).

Comment: What I have outlined is all that is available to you in the current version of Windows 10